# CodeIgniter YouTube API Library Browser Upload

Tags: codeigniter, youtube, youtube-api

First of all, english is not my native language, so I hope you can understand me.

I need to upload videos directly to youtube and I found the library that names the topic. Its pretty nice but I do not understand how to do a browser upload to youtube.

I've the request_youtube() and access_youtube methods working fine(). I recive de tokens and i save them in session but then I get stuck...

I read de documentation here (https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/codeigniter_library) but when I arrive to ‘Sending Data to YouTube - Browser based Uploading’ I feel lost. I dont know how to send that xml data that the doc says. There is no example and I dont know how to do it.

I would like to know if there is any example because its really frustrating hmmm
I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [YouTube Upload Widget](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget).

You can start with integrating the code in [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget#Getting_Started), then you can customize with your needs.

Comment: Hi, I'll try again but yesterday I did and I was not able to get the upload widget workin...only the web cam recorder. I'll try and then answer. Anyway is anybody knows how to do the browser upload with the youtube library for CI will be useful too.

Thanks Ibrahim

Comment: Revision history ".. However, the option to upload an existing file is not currently supported, so the widget always only displays an option to record and upload a webcam video..." :-(